# Debugging in XCode as root

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, sockets, root

In my program I need to create sockets and bind them to listen HTTP port (80). The program works fine when I launch it from command line with sudo, escalating permissions to root. Running under XCode gives a 'permission denied' error on the call to binding function (asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::bind()).

How can I do debugging under XCode?

All done in C++ and boost.asio on Mac OS X 10.5 with XCode 3.1.2.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update**: For Xcode 4.5 and later, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14068416/100478) instead.

---

The only way I'm aware of to do what you're asking is to run Xcode as root.

```
>> sudo /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

Once you're running as root, anything processes launched from Xcode will also run as root.  Note, though, that if you create or edit any files, they will be owned by root, which means that you'll have to `chown` them before you can edit them as your normal user first.

I'd love a way for Xcode to say "Launch process as root", but as far as I know, no such functionality is available.

Note that you can also run the application within the command-line debugger `gdb` to debug your application.  Run

```
>> sudo gdb /path/to/my/application
```

Then you could keep Xcode open, modify at will, and debug your program within gdb. This is what I generally do.

**EDIT**: Readers from the future: see the answer from Alexander Stavonin; it talks about how to do this. If you're okay with ssh keys and enabling the root user on your system, his answer is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, but this problem with files owner is really annoying.

Comment: Unfortunately Alexander's method doesn't seem to work with XCode4, so the sudo method in this answer seems to be the only one that works.

Comment: Readers from the farther future: Xcode now has an option built in: see Mike.R's answer

Answer (score 34):

In Xcode 4.5 <kbd>Product</kbd>-><kbd>Edit Scheme</kbd>: Look in the *Info* tab under *Debug Process As* and choose the *root* option.

Answer (score 15):

Xcode is able to run the debugging application as root. For this purpose the following steps should be done:

1. Enable the root user for local machine.

   a. Run “Directory Utility” (/System/Library/CoreServices/ Directory Utility.app)

   b. Choose “Enable Root User” from the Edit menu and enter the root password.
2. Enable remote loging.

   a.  In System Preferences… -> Sharing, check Remote Login. This option turns on the ssh demon.
3. Create ssh public/private keys and copy public key in the .ssh/authorized_keys folder for root user.

   a. Open terminal on local machine and type `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

   b. Accept the default location and type password for the root.

   c. Login as root `su -` and create ~/.ssh directory. (~ == /var/root)

   d. Copy the public key to the root: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@localhost "cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

   e. Check whether everything is Ok. Type `ssh root@localhost`. It shouldn’t ask for the root password.
4. Enable remote debugging via ssh in Xcode.

   a. Select «Get Info» from drop-down menu on «Executables».

   b. In the "Debugging" settings check «Debug executable remotely via ssh» and put root@localhost as the «Connect to» info.
5. Everything should be Ok now ☺

[From blog](http://stavonin.com/?p=183&language=en)

Comment: It seems I cannot find «Debug executable remotely via ssh» on Xcode4. Is it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. At this moment the best solution for me is GBD in case of root debugging.

Answer (score 3):

XCode no longer supports remote debugging rendering most of these answers obsolete.

For debugging a program as root it is now easy. Under the Product menu, use "Edit Scheme…" and in your "Run" schemes "Info" pane, select "Debug process as root". You will have to authenticate once.

As of Xcode 4.5 I got a strange error until I quite Xcode and restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Debug as a root via SSH.

Edit Active Executable  -> Debugging -> Debug executable remotely via SSH.

Comment: I can't make it working. What I've set on this page: When using "GDB" Use "Pipe" for standard input/output, "Checked" Debug executable remotely via SSH, Connect to: "root@mycomputername.local" ,"Unchecked" Start executable after starting debugger.
And when I'm running my app it shows dialog with SSH authentication but entering my password as passphrase gives "Authentication failed". I also tried to use my user name but it doesn't work too. And, btw, the app doesn't start at all. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug a web server running on port 443, you could instead run it on port 8443 on your normal account and then do a:
sudo ssh user@localhost -L 443:localhost:8443 -N

Then you can still contact your application on the right port, but have the advantage of running the application as a normal user.