# Xcode 4 debugging as root

Tags: debugging, xcode4, root, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug a program that has to run as root. [I found a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033026/debugging-in-xcode-as-root/1866241#1866241) that explains how to use remote debugging to do that. The instructions there and similar instructions out there don't seem to apply to XCode 4. It's possible that I'm just not familiar with the "Executables" item that is referenced. Is there a way to do this in XCode 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's currently no way to do this in Xcode 4. I've filed bugs regarding that lack, and would encourage you to [do the same](http://bugreport.apple.com).