# How to debug a tokend

Tags: macos, tokend

Is it possible (and if: how) to run a custom tokend that is started by securityd in a debugger?
Preferably within the Xcode IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can [start XCode as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033026/debugging-in-xcode-as-root) and then configure the debugger to wait for a new instance of the tokend executable. Once the pcscd signals the presence of a smartcard and the securityd therefore launches a new instance of the tokend the debuger will attach to this new instance.