# XCode: custom lldb or adding args to existing one

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode6, lldb

Recently I found that it's possible to debug via lldb remotely but from command line. So the question: is it possible somehow to replace standard lldb with my version or to have any control over command line which is passed from xcode when it's launched.

there are two reason for doing this:

- pure remote debugging, extremely convenient when debugging focus/eventTarget issues (window/process activation/deactivation)
- debugging of root processes following the manual [Debugging in XCode as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033026/debugging-in-xcode-as-root/14068416#14068416) . I'm aware about "debug as root" in xcode 6 option, but it doesn't work for me for some reason... Also notice that there an option to select a debugger in lld Debugger/Attach to Process/By Process Identifier (PID) or Name... However the option is only.