# How to enable the options of "Debug Process As" in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

The two optional radio buttons are both in disabled state, but I want choose the "root":

[image]

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033026/debugging-in-xcode-as-root) when you searched?

Comment: I've read that post. But you know I don't want to run Xcode in root , I just want to know how to enable “Debug Process As” settings. Why both radio buttons in my Xcode are disabled ?  I have done that “Directory Utility”->Choose “Enable Root User” from the Edit menu, but it still doesn't work. Is it impossible to enable that settings?

Comment: There is more than one answer.  Did you read them all?

Comment: I have looked through all those six answers. And I'm definitely sure. most of the guys advised to change the settings. But my settings are disabled,I just can't change the options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debugging as root only makes sense if you are targetting OSX, not iOS, so that is why it's disabled.

Comment: thank U so much,man. U solved my puzzle.